# garage door handle disconnected from lock

Tags: repair, doors, garage, lock

My garage door is manual at the moment. I’ve had to lock it manually. Today, I realized I can’t lock it from the outside anymore. The handle connected to the lock moves freely and doesn’t move the lock whatsoever. How can I fix this?

Comment: Hard to say, knowing nothing about your hardware. Please describe it in better detail or post photos.

Answer (score 1):

I would take it apart and see what is broken. Unfortunately these days it hard to just replace the broken part. Much faster would be to take it apart and walk in the store and get a complete new assembly which is around $50. If u take it with you they can make sure you get the right one.